# Binning or Averaging spectral matrix according to the specific intervals of the wavelength array

Tags: python, average

My Data is like this:

```
wavelength  reflectance
(nm)          
335           2
338.1         3
341.6         2
343.6         1
347.6         4
351.1         8
359.2         9
362.2         11
364.2         2
365.3         5
366.6         5
368.9         4
373.6         8
```

I want to average the reflectance according to the intervals of 10nm in wavelength. I mean I want the output data similar to this:

```
wavelength    reflectance
340           average(2+3+2+1)
350           average(4+8)
360           average(9+11+2)
370           average(5+5+4+8)
```

Wavelength column shows the center point of the range for example 340 represents the range of 335-345 and reflectance is the average of numbers associated with the wavelengths range of 335-345.

Is there any way to do this in Python? I am very new to Python and trying to bin the data for a hyperspectral signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to first assume that you've figured out how to import the data, and that you have a variable that is an array of tuples, so that for any datapoint `d`, wavelength is represented by `d[0]` and frequency by `d[1]`:

```
data = [(335, 2), (338.1, 3), (341.6, 2), ...]
```

I'll also assume you have this in sorted order - your data seems to imply such, but if not a simple sorting algorithm is both simple to implement and a different question entirely.

I will also assume you have a decent idea of the lower and upper bounds of your data. For example:

```
lower_bound = 330.0
upper_bound = 380.0
```

Finally, you have a "radius" for each group of wavelengths:

```
radius = 5.0
```

Now, see the following:

```
output_list = []
for wavelength in range(lower_bound, upper_bound, radius * 2):
    reflectances = [ d[1] for d in data if ((wavelength - radius) <= d[0] < (wavelength + radius)) ]
    avg_reflectance = sum(reflectances) / len(reflectances)
    output_list.append( (wavelength, avg_reflectance) )
print( output_list )
```

First, we initialize an empty list for our output. Then, we iterate through the region defined by `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`, taking steps of `radius * 2`. For each step, we use python list comprehension to make a list: isolate each `d` in `data` with a wavelength `d[0]` between `(wavelength - radius)` and `(wavelength + radius)`, and get the reflectance `d[1]`. This leaves us with `reflectance` as a list of numbers, which we can easily get the average of. Then, we append a tuple to the output list.

This should yield an output list looking something like this:

```
output_list = [(340.0, 2.0), (350.0, 6.0), ...]
```

which you can then put in whatever format you need.

Comment: This code is working, only if the ranges are not integer, they must be turned into int:                                                                                                                            for wavelength in range(int(lower_bound), int(upper_bound), radius * 2):

Comment: If I have more reflectance data as reflectance2 and reflectance3 until reflectance i, how I can modify this code to calculate the same averaging for more columns (or tuples with i members) and put them in the same output list.